# Using a class's static member on a derived type?

Tags: c#, static, resharper

Using Resharper 4.1, I have come across this interesting warning: "Access to a static member of a type via a derived type". Here is a code sample of where this occurs:

```
class A {
    public static void SomethingStatic() {
       //[do that thing you do...]
    }
}

class B : A {
}

class SampleUsage {
    public static void Usage() {
        B.SomethingStatic(); // <-- Resharper warning occurs here
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what issues there are (if any) when making use of A's static members via B?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

One place where it might be misleading is when the static is a factory method, e.g. the `WebRequest` class has a factory method `Create` which would allow this type of code to be written if accessed via a derived class.

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com");
```

Here `request` is of type `FtpWebRequest` but it's confusing because it looks like it was created from an `HttpWebRequest` (a sibling class) even though the `Create` method is actually defined on `WebRequest` (the base class). The following code is identical in meaning, but is clearer:

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com");
```

Ultimately there's no major problem accessing a static via a derived type, but code is often clearer by not doing so.

Comment: This is an issue I have never thought of before. Thanks Greg!

Comment: great explanation, it was really helpful. First result on google too ^^

Comment: Yeah, fun too when somebody thinks that enough is enough and does implement `Create` on `HttpWebRequest`, hiding the method. Recompile, code break. Many programming languages still think the world stays put.

Answer (score 30):

`B.SomethingStatic()` makes the statement that `SomethingStatic` is a member of `B`.  This is not true.  `SomethingStatic` is unequivocally a member of `A`.  The fact that it's accessible unqualified to members of `B` (as if it were a member of `B`) is a matter of convenience.  The fact that it's accessible when qualified with a `B` is, IMO, a mistake.

Comment: I think a subclass should always inherit every property of a superclass. Especially for the project I'm on right now, It's super helpful with factory patterns.

Comment: I disagree. I have a valid case when the current behavior is beneficial. Here is the idea: `class Validator : ValidatorBase<ThrowStrategy> {}`. Usage: `Validator.CheckNonEmpty(str)`. Compare this to `ValidatorBase<ThrowStrategy>.CheckNonEmpty(str)`.

Comment: @Gebb: I'm afraid I don't see your point.  So you've designed a class hierarchy that's hard to type.  How does that invalidate what I said?  If it were me, I would expect `Validator.CheckNonEmpty`, which appears to be a static member of the `Validator` class, to behave differently from `ValidatorBase<ThrowStrategy>.CheckNonEmpty`, which is provided by a different type.  It doesn't, which is confusing. And if you had another derived class, would you call `CheckNonEmpty` on that, too?  The fact that this misfeature might save you some typing in a certain situation doesn't make it a good feature.

Comment: @PDaddy: It's not the typing that matters, it's the readability. It does appear that `CheckNonEmpty` belongs to the `Validator` class, which it doesn't, but that doesn't matter as long as it's obvious what it does.

Answer (score 15):

It's not a warning, usually, just a suggestion. You're creating a dependency on something unnecessarily.

Suppose you later decide that B doesn't need to inherit A. If you follow Resharper's advice, you won't need to modify that line of code.

Comment: you'd have the same problem with instance methods, too. By all this logic, why inherit anything? 

or am I  missing something?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli - There are those who do recommend avoiding implementation inheritance altogether. Several popular Java and C# books suggest this (see also this paper: http://www.isase.us/wisr3/7.pdf). But in any case, if you do have an instance method `Foo` in `A`, then given an instance of `B` referred to by variable `b`, you don't have the same freedom as in the static case to say "where" `Foo` should be looked up. You have to start with `b`, whatever you do. So it's not really the same as with statics.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I've seen this too, I've always assumed it was just warning me because it was unnecessary. `A.SomethingStatic();` would do the same thing.