# Why "Do not access a static member that is defined in a base class from a derived class."

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

Microsoft's article on [C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) explicitly states:

> "Do not access a static member that is defined in a base class from a
>   derived class."

Why should you not access the static member?

It seems like there are valid scenarios where this should happen, for example all `const` members are static. Should derived classes never be able to read a const member defined in the base class?

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Avoiding “Access to a static member of a type via a derived type”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405953/avoiding-access-to-a-static-member-of-a-type-via-a-derived-type?rq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's use `object.ReferenceEquals` as an example. Here are a few ways you can call this method from a derived class:

```
class A {
 A() {
  ReferenceEquals("a", "b"); //your warning is based on this style
  object.ReferenceEquals("a", "b"); //recommended style
 }
}
```

The fact that `ReferenceEquals` is accessible in `A` is just a coincidence. A static method is independent of any inheritance hierarchy. Therefore, always call it fully qualified from anywhere.

**This warning is just about style and clarity.** All the variants I showed compile to the same IL.

A different interpretation would be that you are misusing inheritance to shorten the syntax used to invoke a method. This is an abuse of inheritance. ASP.NET MVC does this with the Controller base class. It allows you to write `return View();`. It uses inheritance to make a set of methods conveniently available.

Comment: Your first two (accessing it like an instance method) do not compile in C#; maybe you're thinking Java?

Comment: @TimS. indeed, it was Java. Thanks.