# ComputeHash Calls Inexplicably Differ

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, key, message

Why do the following two methods of calling ComputeHash result in different result lengths? Seems like the code should produce equivalent results.

```
byte[] KeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("KgMLuq+k1oCUv5bzTlKAJf/mGo0T07jTogbi6apcqLa114CCPH3rlK4c0RktY30xLEQ49MZ+C2bMyFOVQO4PyA==");
byte[] MessageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ae06fcd3-6447-4356-afaa-813aa4f2ba41;70aa7c25-c74f-48be-8ca8-cbf73627c05f1418068667");

// works
byte[] HashBytes1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(KeyBytes).ComputeHash(MessageBytes); // correct - 32 bytes

// doesn't work
System.Security.Cryptography.HMAC hmac2 = System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256.Create();
hmac2.Key = KeyBytes;
byte[] HashBytes2 = hmac2.ComputeHash(MessageBytes); // wrong - only 20 bytes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simple: look at the remarks of the *static* [`HMAC.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a6y9t8s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

> By default, this overload uses the SHA-1 implementation of HMAC. If you want to specify a different implementation, use the `Create(String)` overload, which lets you specify an algorithm name, instead.

Now `HMACSHA256` inherits from `HMAC`, but it doesn't define it's own static `Create` method. So you would still have to use [`HMAC.Create("HMACSHA256")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kczffhwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

It's probably better to use the `HMAC.Create(String)` than using `HMACSHA256.Create(String)` class here, as not to confuse matters.

Note that the SHA-1 outputs 160 bits or 20 bytes, so this indeed explains the odd output size...

Comment: In Java using a *static* method on anything else than the class that it is defined in can toss a compiler warning. Does anybody know if this is also configurable for C# (and Visual Studio)? Or would this require some kind of static code analysis tool?

Comment: Ah, found it! [ReSharper seems to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660132/using-a-classs-static-member-on-a-derived-type). Not for free though.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN: System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256.Create()

By default, this overload uses the SHA-1 implementation of HMAC. If you want to specify a different implementation, use the Create(String) overload, which lets you specify an algorithm name, instead.

When you call Create currently you are really calling the base class' Create function.

Try:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.HMAC hmac2 = System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256");
```

Yes, I realize how dumb this looks in code form... just trying to answer the question.

As an alternative:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.HMAC hmac2 = System.Security.Cryptography.HMAC.Create("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256");
```